# Entity Framework concurrency with datetime field

Tags: c#, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I have an issue when I update an entity of my model:

```
var intervenant = this.IntervenantRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(intervenant => intervenant.Id == intervenantId);

 if (IsInscrire)
 {
     intervenant.MotifdesinscId = null;
     intervenant.IsInscrit = true;
 }

this.IntervenantRepository.Update(intervenant);
```

I handle concurency with the property `LastModificationTime` in the intervenant entity model:

```
[ConcurrencyCheck] 
public DateTime LastModificationTime { get; set; }
```

When I update my entity with the source code above I get a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, and I think the problem is that the data in that I get in my property LastModificationTime is 2020-03-09T10:02:37, but in the database the column contains the data 2020-03-09 10:02:37.4570000.

Is there any solution that can let me handle this problem because I get it also in other entity ?

Comment: The date is just being display in a different format.  Not sure if there is a type issue where the seconds are different by 14 seconds in the two dates.

Comment: yes the problem is when i get  the intervenant entity, i get its property LastModificationTime with value 2020-03-09T10:02:37 without the .4570000 and when i try to make the update that causes the problem because the data in database is 2020-03-09 10:02:37.4570000

Comment: Time on a PC is accurate to 100nsec.  So you need find out why the time is getting truncated in the code to seconds.

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server is a bad choice for concurrency control - it's only accurate to **3.33ms** - thus you might get "wrong" duplicates. I would **strongly recommend** that you use a proper, separate `ROWVERSION` column - that's what it's all about and that's the most reliable way to handle optimistic concurrency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to modify my entity configuration, and delete this line :

```
.HasColumnType("datetime")
```

and with this configuration i have not the problem anymore :

```
 builder.Property(e => e.LastModificationTime)
            .HasColumnName("INTERVENANT_MODIFQUAND");
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to ignore the `LastModificationTime` property altogether and use the `TimestampAttribute`. This is effectively what @marc_s suggests in his comment.

```
public class Intervenant
{
    // Your properties here

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

[TimeStamp-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/TimeStamp-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

It uses a byte array that represents the timestamp in order to avoid such issues as the one you have.

> It can only be applied once in an entity class to a byte array type property. **It creates a column with timestamp data type** in the SQL Server database. Entity Framework API automatically uses this Timestamp column in concurrency check on the UPDATE statement in the database.

If you don't want to use multiple values and let the framework handle it on it's own use this. It will extend the table a bit but it will solve any such issues.

`ConcurrencyCheckAttribute`

Comment: it's a solution but i cannot do it, we have lot of entities and we choose to work with lastModificationTime in the project. the solution i found is to delete this line .HasColumnType("datetime") in the coffiguration of my entity

Comment: This is decent but it ignores edge cases that AND the mechanism already in there which is way more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge when trying to use EF and a DateTime field as the concurrency check field. It appears the EF concurrency code doesn't honor the precision setting from the metadata (edmx) i.e. Type="DateTime" Precision="3".
The database datetime field will store a millisecond component within the field (i.e. 2020-10-18 15:49:02.123). Even if you set the original value of the Entity to a DateTime that includes the millisecond component, the SQL EF generates is this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[People]
SET [dateUpdated] = @0
WHERE (([PeopleID] = @1) AND ([dateUpdated] = @2))
-- @0: '10/19/2020 1:07:00 AM' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @1: '3182' (Type = Int32)
-- @2: '10/19/2020 1:06:10 AM' (Type = DateTime2)
```

As you can see, @2 is a STRING representation without a millisecond component. This will cause your updates to fail.

Therefore, if you're going to use a DateTime field as a concurrency key, you must STRIP off the milliseconds/Ticks from the database field when retrieving the record and only pass/update the field with a similar stripped DateTime.

```
    //strip milliseconds due to EF concurrency handling
    PeopleModel p = db.people.Where(x => x.PeopleID = id);
    if (p.dateUpdated.Millisecond > 0)
    {
        DateTime d = new DateTime(p.dateUpdated.Ticks / 10000000 * 10000000);
        object[] b = {p.PeopleID, d};
        int upd = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update People set dateUpdated=@p1 where peopleId=@p0", b);
        if (upd == 1)
            p.dateUpdated = d;
        else
            return InternalServerError(new Exception("Unable to update dateUpdated"));
    }
return Ok(p);
```

And when updating the field with a new value, strip the milliseconds also

```
(param)int id, PeopleModel person;
People tbl = db.People.Where(x => x.PeopleID == id).FirstOrDefault();
db.Entry(tbl).OriginalValues["dateUpdated"] = person.dateUpdated;
//strip milliseconds from dateUpdated since EF doesn't preserve them
tbl.dateUpdated = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks / 10000000 * 10000000);
```